# Using sqlite database in heroku

Tags: docker, sqlite, heroku, continuous-integration

I am using a SQLite database which is integrated inside source-code which is being used when the application is deployed on Heroku. As per [SQLite on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3), `Instead of using SQLite on Heroku you can configure your app to run on Postgres.` Is there any way to find a workaround on this.

I am using git ci and docker to deploy my code on heroku.

Comment: Assuming you don't want to lose that data frequently and without notice, no, there is no workaround.